# USB Serial communication stops with "Resource Temporarily Unavailable", preceeded by receiving random characters

Tags: serial-port

I'm using an ftdi serial port converter. After opening the converter using microcom, I will eventually see these characters spew to the screen "DDFDDFDFD", then I get this message: `Resource temporarily unavailable`.  I've uninstalled brltty, disabled ModemManager and looked at using `lsof` to find a process that is using the `/dev/ttyUSB0` resource.  None of this fixes the issue.

```
Linux gandalf 5.19.0-50-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 18:24:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
```